How to automatically tag e-mails in a way that Thunderbird will recognize via IMAP?
I have a number of e-mail addresses, all aliased to one mailbox.org account. However, I'd like to be able to label the e-mails by which of my e-mail addresses they were sent to/from, like for example Gmail or Skiff does, so that I may at a glance see which is the relevant address and use it to filter my e-mails when needed:
 
I'm using Thunderbird as my e-mail client, fetching my e-mails from mailbox.org via IMAP. How do I automatically tag incoming and outgoing e-mails with the correct e-mail address in a way that Thunderbird will recognize and that will synchronize to other clients I use via IMAP?

The canonical way to handle labels or tags via IMAP is using custom so-called IMAP keywords. I've heard of e-mail providers that don't provide support for these, but most should.
First, set up automatic IMAP keyword tagging criteria with your e-mail provider. You will need a filter for each e-mail address you wish to tag. Each filter will need to check for the relevant e-mail address in both the To and From fields, and as an action, add an IMAP keyword named after the e-mail address.
In the case of mailbox.org, this can be achieved by navigating to Settings → Mail → Filter Rules → Add new rule and filling in the following:

Next, set up matching tags in Thunderbird. Navigate to Settings → Tags → New…. One little niggle to be aware of is that at least in mailbox.org's case – and perhaps with other e-mail providers as well – the IMAP keyword added is prepended with a $. (For example, if you add example@mydomain.me as an IMAP keyword, the IMAP keyword added behind the scenes is instead $example@mydomain.me. There is no simple way to inspect this – I ended up communicating with the IMAP server manually to be sure.) Thus, the tag added to Thunderbird may need to be prepended with a $:

Et voila! Thunderbird should now automatically label your e-mails with the correct e-mail address when fetching from the server.
If you wish to remove the $, you can do so by navigating to Thunderbird's Settings → Config Editor…, searching for the setting mailnews.tags.$example@mydomain.me.tag (substituting with your e-mail address, of course), and editing the value to remove the $. (Internally, the correct IMAP keyword will still be used.)

